# Putting Multiline Conditional Equations

Tags: conditionals

I am trying to write two equation like,

```
a=b      when a>1
a=c      when a=0
```

One obvious choice is putting all in a `tabular` construct, as,

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
$a=b$ & \text{when $a\ge 1$}\\
$a=c$ & \text{ $when a=0$}
\end{tabular}
```

But, the spacing looks rather odd.
I tried putting them in `cases` construct, but it is more suitable for conditional functions, as I am getting a brace at left.

So, what is the preferred way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three options using `align*` or `aligned` from the `amsmath` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
a &= b,\quad\text{when $a\ge 1$.}\\
a &= c,\quad\text{when $a=0$.}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
a &= b,&&\text{when $a\ge 1$.}\\
a &= c+e,&&\text{when $a=0$.}
\end{align*}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
a &= b,&&\text{when $a\ge 1$.}\\
a &= c+e,&&\text{when $a=0$.}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the first option, it's assumed that both math expressions on the right hand side have the same length; in the other options this is not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

```
%\documentclass{article}% uncomment this line if you want to use article class
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}% comment this line if you want to use other class

\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax% remove this line because it is used just for creating a screenshot like image file.
\[
\begin{aligned}
    ax^2 + bx + c &= 0 && \text{when } a \ne 0\\
    y &= mx + c && \text{when } m \ne 0
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]